# Getting IP address of remote VPN server

Tags: networking, command-line, iptables, openvpn, vpn

Is there a way to obtain the IP address of the remote VPN gateway that a running OpenVPN client is tunneled into, via the command line?

More detail: Suppose OpenVPN is connected to a remote server, launched via the command line with the option `--remote`, or by specifying a .opvn file in which 'remote' is given, or launched by Network Manager in Ubuntu, say. How can I via the command line get the IP address of the remote VPN server?

A hack that could work in some contexts is to run `ps aux | grep openvpn` and then regex-match the `--remote` command line argument, but I'd like something more reliable.

(This might be a duplicate of [Reliably get OpenVPN tunnel server IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354518/reliably-get-openvpn-tunnel-server-ip) , but that question has not received any activity and I'm not 100% sure the intention is the same there.)

Background: I'm interested in this question on its own, but here's some motivation; tips on other ways to solve this would also be welcome.
I'd like to block, via `iptables`, any traffic not going through the VPN tunnel. For this I'm using, as part of other rules,

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d $serverip -j ACCEPT
```

and it seems that this needs to be the external IP of the server, rather than the local IP of the server (10.x.x.1 or whatever).

Comment: Why the downvote? It's my first time asking a question here so an explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If just looking inside the .ovpn file is not an option i would probably write a little lua script parsing the .ovpn file and resolving the dns and running whatever iptables command it needs to run with that address. You dont need to do that in lua you can use any scripting language your comfortable with.

As for command line tools that do this out of the box, none come to mind.
You kinda answered your own question altho this only gives me the command line arguments which for all my vpn clients are only openvpn xxxx.ovpn so that wouldnt even work on my system.

Sidenote: If you really want this reliably for any openvpn client you could also specify a proxy server inside the .ovpn file and implement a quick one yourself with something like nodejs (Openvpn does support HTTP/1.0 CONNECT proxies for tcp and SOCKS5 for UDP however SOCKS5 is harder to implement quickly especially the UDP part of that). There you would get the IP address reliably as soon as openvpn connects and you could run your iptables command before you open the socket to the remote host.

Btw, i had the a very similar problem and i ended up buying a iot device that acts as a router, altho i cannot recommend the one i got (Banana Pi BPI R1) it now works and does its job, it was a pain to set it up there probably are better alternatives to that device.

The "Trick" i used, was on that IOT Router, i was blocking all FORWARDING unless it was having the vpn tun tap device as input or output. This works because the vpn client itself is only affected by the output/input chain, completely circumventing the problem.

Another advantage to this is, that the paid VPN provider does not know how many devices i am using (I am limited to 3 by mine) at any given time. All the VPN provider sees is that my iot router is having a lot of traffic and is connected 24/7.